# Index not defined; select option wasn't dynamically selected

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

having this challenge i think is more of frontend where i needed to save through api, actually not the way i expected it to work,

the challenge is that i have to hardcode the index to be 0 through FormData before i can bypass the logic and save to db, in other words the select option wasn't dynamically selected

below is the code, though i know it is more more of list thing but i stuck needs help

```
  const [company, setCompany] = useState([])

  const createAssigned = () => {
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('post', postid.id)
  // this part is the issue kindly help to addressed more appreciated
  formData.append('carrier', company[index].id) 
  assignPost(formData)
    .then(data => {
      if(data.status === 201){
        toast.success('You have successfully assigned this vehicle')
      }else{
        toast.warning("Error in assigning vehicle")
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      alert(error.message)
    })
 }


 const assignPost = (body) => {
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/assigned/`,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        body: body
    })
   }

  <select 
    className="form-control select2"
    value={company}
    onChange={(e)=> setCompany(e.target.value)}
   >                     
     {company.map((c) => (
        <option key={c.id}>{c.busname}</option>                                       
     ))} 
   </select>

views.py
   class AllBusinessName(viewsets.ViewSet):
      queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
      serializer_class = GetUserBusinessSerializer

      def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       try:
         qs = self.queryset.filter(is_carrier=True)
         serializer = GetUserBusinessSerializer(qs, many=True)
         return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
       except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

serializers
   class GetUserBusinessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
       model = CustomUser
       fields = ['id','busname']
```